# SQL complicated sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine this tables:

```
| USER |
|------|
| _id  |

| PHOTO |
|-------|
|  _id  |
|  user | - who uploaded it

| RATING |
|--------|
| user   | - who vote
| photo  | - for which foto
```

And then I need to extract All photos uploaded by **$user** And on top of that, what rating the photo has...

for example:

```
USER
1

PHOTO
50    |    1
51    |    1
52    |    1

RATING
2     |    50
3     |    51
2     |    51
2     |    52
4     |    51
3     |    50
```

My Expected result for function get_info($id):

```
$id = 1;

result:
_id   |  rating
50    |    2
51    |    3
52    |    1
```

Is there possible one task sql ? thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. read up about [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)s

Comment: Can you provide some example on this case? I've been trying for an hour now and with no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use join and count with group by

```
select p._id,count(distinct r.user)
from photo p
join rating r on(p._id=r.photo)
where p.user = 1
group by p._id
```

Since your photo table has an association with rating table as _id is related to the photo column of rating table so join them, then count each distinct user for each photo

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce76b/1)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your post, is it possible to show also records that don't have any rating ?

Comment: @MichalHeneš yes just change join to left join so if any photo which doesn't have a rating yet will also be in result set but with a 0 count value